# Como posso criar um CheckBox utilizando o Helper Html.CheckBoxFor para um campo Nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Meu campo está da seguinte forma em minha classe:

```
public bool? meuCampo { get; set; }
```

E em minha view está assim:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.meuCampo)
```

Só que dessa forma não é permitido, porque não posso converter explicitamente o tipo `bool?` para `bool`, então para tentar resolver isso fiz da forma abaixo, usando `cast`:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => (bool)m.meuCampo)
```

Pórem, assim também ocorre um erro que é o seguinte:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Então de acordo com os fatos, teria alguma outro forma de criar checkbox, utilizando o `Helper` `Html`, com propriedades do tipo `Nullable<bool>`?

Answer (score 5):

Vale a pena dar uma olhada em EditorTemplates do Asp.NET MVC. Eles possuem um padrão de CoC (Convention over Configuration) de implementação. Para configurar você pode criar um template em:

Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Boolean.cshtml

```
@model Boolean?
@Html.CheckBox("", Model.HasValue && Model.Value)
```

E utilizar na sua view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m)
```

Exemplo: [Extending Editor Templates for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/)

Answer (score 4):

Yuri, o `CheckBoxFor` espera um bool, isto pq o `checked` tem apenas dois estados, selecionado ou não.

opcionalmente você pode usar o `HtmlHelper.CheckBox` e informar o nome da propriedade como string.

```
@Html.CheckBox("meuCampo", Model.HasValue && Model.Value)
```

caso realmente precise trabalhar com três estados, utilize o attributo `indeterminate`:

```
@{
dynamic htmlAttributes = new ExpandoObject();
if (!Model.HasValue)
    htmlAttributes.indeterminate = "indeterminate";
}
@Html.CheckBox("meuCampo", Model.HasValue && Model.Value, htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, Object>;)
```